Why does this member inline snippet throw an FS1113 error (inline but uses internal or private)?
This two-liner:
type SomeType(x) =
    member inline _.Value = x

Throws this error:
      member inline _.Value = x
  --------------------^^^^^
/home/user/stdin(2,21): error FS1113: The value 'Value' was marked inline but its implementation makes use of an internal or private function which is not sufficiently accessible

Bizarrely, this compiles:
type SomeType(x) =
    member inline x.Value = x


The reason for the error is that x is an argument to the SomeType constructor, so it is stored as an internal value within the type. Decompiled into C#, the constructor looks like this:
    {
        internal object x;

        public SomeType(object x)
        {
            this.x = x;
        }
    }

Because x is internal, it is not eligible to be inlined.
The reason your second example compiles is that it declares a new x that shadows the original x that was passed to the constructor. In C# terms, the method now returns this, which can be inlined.

Thanks Brian.  Interesting.  I'm trying to define types that use constrained generics (eg, SomeType<'T when 'T: comparison>(x: 'T) = ...) that need validation.  Hence, classes instead of records, so I can force validation in the constructor.  Is there no way to get classes to work with generics?

You can define classes with generics, as long as you don't try to inline the constructor arguments. But you can also use a record type with private fields if you want to force validation through a "constructor" function. E.g. type SomeType<'T when 'T: comparison> = private { Value : 'T }. You might want to ask this as a separate question if you need more help.
